# I want to restrict user from entering text other than (My case : "T+1") at runtime through regex

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

requirement is to restrict User from typing wrong characters in the field itself rather than throwing any error or clearing of invalid input.

i tried following regex:

```
(^[T|t]{1}[-|+][1-9][0-9]$)|(^[T|t]{1}[-|+][1-9]$)|^[T|t]$
```

Basically what is happening in my code is, i have one textbox and combobox. if user  enters T + any value which is in range (2,99) then i have to disable combobox. but it is only working with lostfocus of textbox and i want the validation logic and disabling logic to be called simultaneously once user starts typing in.

i have an workflow activity which when loaded shows T+1 value. In that if i added value between 2 and 99 then it disables the combo box. but when i clear that whole field in textbox and when i enter T it shows T , now when i enter + sign whole text field is cleared. this is becuase i have added logic for it as if that string in textbox is invalid(not according to regex) then clear the field.

what i want now is allow user to type in but restrict him typing in repetations.at same time string from textbox should be evaluated and combobox should be disabled.

please help. In need of serious help.

Comment: Please add more code besides the regular expression. It's difficult to see why it's not working with just a description of the issue.

Comment: Do you want to allow `T+` and then any number between `1` to `99`?

Comment: wiktor i want any num between 2 and 99 along with T+ or T-

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're question is actually quite simple;

> "but it is only working with lostfocus of textbox and i want the
>   validation logic and disabling logic to be called simultaneously once
>   user starts typing in"

Just use the PreviewTextInput event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm wilfully ignoring the fact there's more than one question there :P